# Keep old values if not present in the json when deserialize

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have such a class:

```
public class item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Pw { get; set; }
}
```

from which I create several objects I store in the DB. Then I want to update one of them with data coming from client in the form of a json like this:

```
{  
   "Name":"John",
   "City":"NYC"
}
```

the idea would be to use:

```
item myitem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<item>(jsoncomingfromclient);
```

but doing so Pw is overwritten with null (while obviously I want to keep the original value)

[NullValueHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) looks like a good candidate but it works if the value is null, in my case it is completely missing from the json. 
Any idea how to deserialize a json keeping the old value in the destination object if the value is missing in the json?

Comment: Your example doesn't include an "original value" at all... it sounds like you should just be writing a merge routine between two `item` values. (Ideally, fix the names at the same time to be more idiomatic...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JsonConvert.PopulateObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm).  It's designed for this purpose:

```
        var item = new item { Name = "my name", City = "my city", Pw = "my pw" };

        var json = @"
        {  
           ""Name"":""John"",
           ""City"":""NYC""
        }";

        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, item);

        Debug.Assert(item.Pw == "my pw"); // no assert
        Debug.Assert(item.Name == "John"); // no assert
        Debug.Assert(item.City == "NYC"); // no assert
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of code `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<item>(jsoncomingfromclient);` will create new instance of type `item` based on parameter `jsoncomingfromclient` and return it.

This part `item myitem = ...` declares a variable `myitem` of type `item` and gives it a concrete instance. So there is no way to merge anything like this.

You just have to write some merge method manually and define what and how is merged between two objects.

---

Something like that

```
item dbitem = ...
item myitem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<item>(jsoncomingfromclient);
item mergedItem = myitem.merge(dbitem)
```

Comment: Obviously this is just an example, in the real case the class/json have tens (an hundred?) items. I ca't merge after the deserialization as myitem would have null values (I could keep the old value if the new is null but doing so I would make impossibile to update with null and old value and this could be necessary). So I'd need to merge "during" deserialization. Any ideas is more than welcome.